# Getting latest data from a Web URL in Python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, urllib

I am trying to read data from an internal WEB URL that contains a list of reports uploaded periodically as follows:

```
Date/Time    Created By  Status Action
----------   ---------   ------ --------
Jul 4, 2023  Dummy1      Done   Download
Jun 4, 2023  Dummy2      Done   Download
May 4, 2023  Dummy3      Done   Download
```

The Action field is a Download link which triggers a download of the corresponding csv when clicked. The Date/Time, Created By and Status field *headers only are clickable* and can be clicked in order to sort the data as required.

I have a working code which I update every month with the link to the Download button of the latest report and data gets pulled in as expected.
The code snippet for the relevant part:

```
url='https://api.test/v1/reports/download'
def fetch_source_data():
    try:
        weburl = urllib.request.urlopen(str(url))
    except HTTPError as err:
        while attempts:
            i+=1
            print("URL: %s unreachable ... Retrying...Attempt# %s" %(url,i))
            time.sleep(10)
            try:
                weburl = urllib.request.urlopen(str(url))
                print("Succeeded accessing %s on Attempt# %s"%(url,i))
                break
            except HTTPError:
                attempts-=1
                if not(attempts):
                    print("All Attempts for accessing %s Exhausted.. Exiting"%(url))
                    sys.exit(1)
    resp = weburl.read().decode('utf-8')
    lines = resp.splitlines(True)
    nlines = len(lines)
    print("The loop will run %d times in the final report"%nlines)
```

I am trying to updated my code so that it can detect and trigger the latest download link every month so that I do not have to make any manual updates. Can someone please suggest some method?

I am also constrained by the fact that I must use only the standard / base Python packages which I have been using for the development until now. I am running my current code successfully on Python 3.6.8 and Python 3.10.11

Comment: Am I correct in saying you're asking 2 things here?  1) how can you download/process the latest file without duplicating a download and 2) how can you automate the running of this Python code monthly?

Comment: Hello.  yes.. my question is how to download / process the latest file.  I do have a cronjob currently that helps me run my current code monthly so that part is fine.. Thanks.

Comment: "I am trying to updated my code so that it can detect and trigger the latest download link every month " - where does this download link come from? I'm assuming it changes? There isn't enough information here to answer your question. If the download link doesn't change, just use the same URL. If it does, see if you can find a pattern. If it comes from another web page, you can make a HTTP request to that resource and parse the 'download link' you are interested in.

Comment: Thank you. Yes the link is not static. It is hosted on an internal site and is generated monthly by a scheduled job over which I have no control. When clicked, a csv is downloaded. The url is constant up to a point after which some random codes are appended. For example, the Download URL for the July report is 'api.test/reports/7a87c099-931s-461f-bbf0-0bz6w0d2413a/download' and for June 'api.test/reports/01b6c079-019r-225y-qwf7-9gu8v0dm191d/download'. Since I could not find any pattern, I wanted to check if there is some way to grab the latest link from the site.

Answer (score 0):

to answer your question about what I assume is a changing download link. i.e. one month it is https://api.test/v1/reports/download/202306 and next month it is https://api.test/v1/reports/download/202307 you could make a variable that matches the desired pattern.

```
import datetime

base_url = "https://api.test/v1/reports/download/"
now = datetime.datetime.now()
month = now.strftime("%m")
year = now.strftime("%Y")

url = base_url + year + month + ".zip"
```

Comment: Thanks .. yes the download link is variable but it is far more complex in terms of the way it updates. Hence the though of grabbing the latest URL.